# Speed of two queries versus one query but limit output

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query where i need to know the number of lines total in a table but only need to show the first 6.

So, is it faster to run `select count(*)` then `select * ... limit 6` and print data returned? Or, just `select *` with no limit and put a counter in the while loop printing the results? With the latter I can obviously use mysql_num_rows to get the total.

The table in question will contain up to 1 million rows, the query includes a where row = xxx that column will be indexed

Comment: Reading the whole table scales .. poorly, especially for large result sets that are not streamed (I have no idea if PHP supports streamed result sets). Even with streaming, an operation like `mysql_num_rows` would force the entire stream to be materialized (e.g. read in all N records) excepting where the server already supplied such information .. again, not good if it needs to scale.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). Here's an example:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do two queries.  Your count query will use an index and will not have to scan the whole table, only the index.  The second query will only have to read the 6 rows from the table.